# Select result from multi tables with joins

Tags: sql, 4d-database

I have this query. I want to select the

> surgery Type
>   surgery Details
>   Modality ID

Am I on the right path atleast?

The `LINK` table is the middle of everything

> `Addmission` 1toM  on `LINK`
>   `Surgery`    Mto1  on `LINK`
>   `Modality`   Mto1  on `LINK`

My problem is just add in `Modality.ID` to the result.
skip modality, and the query works 100%

**updated** (dropped multi alias)

```
SELECT surg.srg_Details, surg.Type, modd.ID
FROM Surgery surg
JOIN LINK lnk on lnk.lnk_ID = surg.srg_lnkID
JOIN Modality modd ON modd.mod_lnkID = lnk.lnk_ID
JOIN Admission adm ON adm.adm_ID = lnk.lnk_admID
WHERE  adm.adm_ID = 192100042
```

Comment: Please show sample sample data and desired results.  A non-working query doesn't do much to convey what you really need to do.

Comment: yikes, how is this even running?, you are joining `Modality` twice, and with the same alias even

Comment: @Lamak. fair point. I did try it without, but it remains a "General Error", what ever that implies. Mod is also a reserved word, so opted for `modd`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: 4th Dimension's SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use in this case:

```
SELECT surg.srg_Details, surg.Type, mod.ID
FROM Surgery surg, Modality mod
JOIN LINK lnk on lnk.lnk_ID = surg.srg_lnkID
JOIN Admission adm ON adm.adm_ID = lnk.lnk_admID
WHERE  adm.adm_ID = 192100042 AND surg.srg_lnkID = mod.mod_lnkID
```

Comment: Im using RazorSQL and it only gives me a "General error". so Im not sure why. I had it like you have here, but same thing happens.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: 4th Dimension's SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to use left Join though no match null value will be present

SELECT surg.srg_Details, surg.Type, mod.ID
FROM Surgery surg, Modality mod
left JOIN LINK lnk on lnk.lnk_ID = surg.srg_lnkID
left JOIN Modality mod ON mod.mod_lnkID = lnk.lnk_ID
left JOIN Admission adm ON adm.adm_ID = lnk.lnk_admID
WHERE  adm.adm_ID = 192100042
```